Why is there bamboo in 筋?
Why does 筋 have bamboo at the top part? Surely tendons and muscles are related to flesh 肉 and strength 力, and even looks a bit like muscle 肌, but I can't seem to find a reason why there is bamboo 竹 on top as it doesn't seem to contribute phonetically or semantically. Is it purely a decorative component to distinguish from 肋/肌?

According to what I'm finding from a few sources, I think semantic 竹 is used here for 筋 (jīn; muscles, tendons) because the original meaning of the character is "bamboo sinew (e.g. the material used to make bows with)".

I'll write up an answer for you if I find any further information.

Ji Xusheng's, A New Textual Research on Origin of Chinese Characters, p. 351 has the following entry:



Here it is shown that the original meaning was:

释义：竹筋

This is further referenced and translated in Outlier's Dictionary of
Chinese Characters:

In 筋,  “bamboo leaves hanging down; bamboo” is a  meaning component, pointing to the  original meaning “bamboo sinew.”

The extension of meanings from there is then fairly logical. See Outlier's meaning tree:

1 (orig.) bamboo sinew
2 → tendon
3 → muscle fiber
‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎4 ⇒ muscle


what is that strange looking character with flesh and knife? I've never seen it before. So the "strength" was actually a "knife"?

@Fishuman That's a variant character, or graphical corruption, of 剝, used semantically to mean "to peel" in 筋.

This character: ? http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=206E7


Why does 筋 have bamboo at the top part?

To distinguish ribs, bone, from actual meat, which is muscles and tendons.
Mostly, bones and flesh come together.
筋骨：jīngǔ：physique
肋骨 lèi gǔ ：rib(s)
筋：jīn,qián：muscles; tendons
肋： lèi,lē,jīn：ribs; chest
肉：⺼：ròu,rù：ribs
力：lì：power, capability, influence
竹：zhú：bamboo （2个）
Imagine you are an ancient Chinaman. You want to represent meat with a little ideograph. What would you draw? A blob? But if you represent meat with bone, the task becomes easier: ⺼. Actually draw the bones and the infer the meat attached thereto, the poor pig split asunder!
肋骨骨折
fractured rib （ouch)

Let's trace the root word of 筋:
【集韻】筋，古文竻字。註見六畫。
竻 《康熙字典》- 【集韻】歷德切，音勒。竹根也。
Bamboo Roots:

